# How to recover from locked down XP Home computer

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, kiosk

We've got a Kiosk machine provided to us by a manufacturer.  The video card is flaky, so I want to replace it with another card we have on hand, rather than shipping across the country.

The problem is that they have policies in place that locks the system down to a point where only the manufacturers demo works on the computer so I can't install drivers for the newer card.

I know pretty much nothing about windows policies or the policy editor.

Am I fighting a losing battle trying to replace thi scard?

Comment: What's your level of physical access to the machine? Can you boot it from a CD or a flash drive?

Comment: Yes, can boot from external media.

Comment: My suggestion would be to install the new card, then boot from the OS disk to install the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the new video card, then boot into *Safe Mode With Command Prompt*.

To start Windows Installer in "Safe Mode with command prompt":

1. Restart your computer and press <kbd>F8</kbd> before the boot menu or splash screen
2. Select *Safe Mode With Command Prompt*
3. In the command window type the following two commands and press Enter:

   `REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\MSIServer" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"`

   `net start msiserver`

Once msiserver is running you can install your driver. Be sure to include spaces and quotes in those two commands.

While you are in safe mode, create a new user account with admin privileges. After a reboot see if it shows up at login - if it does you can use that account to perform your needed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try to log on into administrator, if you doesn't have the password, you can use this Linux tool: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

But in my opinion, I don't think the manufacturer would be happy of that...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.  For what it's worth, currently I'm not presented with any login prompt at all.  CTRL+ALT+DEL doesn't even work.

It's locked down because it's a working demo of a game for public use.  It needs to be locked, all I want to do is open it enough to install drivers.